# Tkinter GUI doesn't work outside iPython

Tags: user-interface, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm rather unfamiliar with Python, but am attempting to make a simple gui with tkinter (Python 2.7.x).  I have one fully functional button, but I can only get the script to work in iPython.  When I try to run it outside of the iPython environment, I see some text run down the command prompt but nothing happens (ie no gui appears, no action happens).

My code:

```
    import Tkinter
    from Tkinter import *
    import os

    #define frame
    root = Tk()

    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()


    #define buttons
    button = Button(frame, text="Action", command= lambda: os.system("Action.py"))
    button.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `root.mainloop()` to the end of your code.